# How can I create standard document?

Tags: fonts, floats, custom-bib

I like create standard format in my document like:

-All the text are justify until I swap this part of text only (center, right, left);

-Standard margin of document (top, bottom, left, right);

-Standard font type;

Example:
I'm new these, so in all my pages, I put

```
\begin{justify}
    Text, text, text ....
\end{justify}
```

If I think on long-term, it is not feasible.

Font type I not change (I don't know how to do).

Margin I not change too (I use a standard a4paper)(but I need in these measures: top=3,bottom=2,left=3,right=2).

Comment: there really isn't any accepted *international* standard, so you need to say exactly what you consider to be "standard", particularly with respect to margins.  however, in every "basic" document class i'm aware of, justified text is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than re-creating the wheel, it's best to just base your document on one of the standard classes. The `article` class is about as standard as you can get, but `memoir` and the KOMA-script classes are good options as well. When using `article`, you can specify the margins with the `geometry` package, but the layout is already justified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note: the `lipsum` package is just for dummy text.

[image]

Comment: I use the \documentclass{article}, but it not justify for me. :(
This is my documentclass
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesAlmeida If you try with exactly the code I posted above does it look the same?

Comment: I'm very distrated! In my book cover and cover page I increase \centering. In cover page, I have quote on right. I compare all the text in these quote who have \centering! The text 'normal' are justify automatic. Sorry and thank you! :D